# Pass Record Details(Id) to Visualforce page opened via hyperlink in an email

Tags: apex, visualforce

Wondering if this situation is possible to implement or not?

Here's the scenario, changes in a record forwards an email alert via workflow. That email consists of a link to a sites page..here's my dillema.. is there a way to populate record details on that visualforce sites page which was opened via the link in the email template?

The flow is something like this..
Field update forwards the email-> Email template has sites page link-> User clicks the link to open a VF sites page -> Auto populate the record details which the user is supposed to evaluate

Any insights will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

In your email template how are you generating the sites page link ?

I would have thought you could use a merge field to populate the record ID. Then in the controller for the Sites page link, you could use to get the record ID and then query to retrieve all the info required for the page.

`ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');`

In a nutshell, set a query parameter in the email template and then have an action on the controller that checks for that parameter and queries the database for the required info. The link below might also be of help

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_system_pagereference.htm